# Get the power value of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Probably very simple to do, but can't figure a way to do it.

Trying to find a way of getting the power value of a cell that is written in scientific notation (i.e. 1*10^x).

An example would be:

Cell value: 1.39E***+04***, or 1.94E***-12***

Value needing to be extracted: **+04**, **-12**

Need to do it using either the formulae or functions of Excel, no VBA.

Comment: What is your original data's format like? is it actually a number or is it text?

Comment: It's written as a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a number in **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"0.00E+00"),3)
```

It does not matter if **A1** format is `Scientific` or not:

[image]

**NOTE:**

This method avoids using any `LOG()` functions.
This method should work on any **numeric** value *(not text)*.
This method should work regardless of how the numeric value is formatted.

Comment: Thank you. This works well. Knew it was something simple

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Just tried it and it worked fine.................Just be sure the value in **A1** is **number** and not **string**!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data is in cell D7:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(D7,"@"),LEN(TEXT(D7,"@"))-FIND("E",TEXT(D7,"@")))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula works for positive powers, but not negative powers (e.g. +19, but not -05)